# mysql views not changes on alter original table

Tags: mysql, view

I create a view for example

```
CREATE VIEW testView AS SELECT * FROM tbEjemplo;
```

Then I add a new field to table tbEjemplo and I cannot see that new field on testView
I'm doing something wrong or is a "limitation"?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Simply look at `SHOW CREATE TABLE testView;` output... you MUST re-create a view.

Comment: So, there is no simple way to update the view?